# Azure AD Graph API does not contain all audit events

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I sign into the Security and Compliance page and perform an audit log search I see the events I expect to, such as login events and mailbox logins (Mailbox auditing is enabled). I was hoping to get this same functionality from the Graph API.

I've created an app with Read Directory application rights and can access the Graph API just fine. However when I pull the AuditEvent report, events such as PasswordLogonInitialAuthUsingPassword and MailboxLogin simply aren't present.

I went ahead and created a different app using the Office Management Activity API and after starting subscriptions for Audit.Exchange and Audit.AzureActiveDirectory I see all the events I normally see in the Web UI.

I could certainly be wrong, but it seems like the Graph API is the future so I'd prefer to leverage that for my application. Is the aforementioned information available in the Graph API or should I leverage the Management Activity API? I'm also interested in pulling other reports such as the following which appear to only be present withing Graph:

- CompromisedCredentialsEvent
- IrregularSignInActivityEvent
- AllUsersWithAnomalousSignInActivityEvent

It feels I'm missing something with the Graph API so any guidance would be appreciated.